# How can we define length unambiguously when measurement of length is dependent on perspective?

Tags: optics, measurements, geometry

Suppose I have two unmarked rulers, both of same length in one perspective. Let me keep them at some place in the room , and I view them from another. In the other point of viewing, the perceived lengths have distorted and no longer are the two ruler lengths equal. For instance, if I took a photo of them and tried to measure the length of the two rulers in the photo, it will be different.

So, when we define measurement, shouldn't we also remark on what prespective we are doing it from? However no physics book I have read does it. If this problem is simply ignorable, could it be explained why it is so?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3):

Length and area are invariant; the angle and solid angle they respectively subtend [are not](https://youtu.be/MMiKyfd6hA0).

Comment: Are you really saying that the dimensions of an object does not vary depending on where you look at it from? THen why does a building seem to have a larger area when we are close to it?

Comment: @Buraian Like I said, what's actually larger is subtended solid angle, which is measured in steradians, not square metres.

Comment: When we speak of angle, we are implicitly assuming there is a seperation between us and the object to, and then, describing the size of the object both those variables. I believe the resolution of this issue can be done without this extra concept. Suppose one measured the edge length of an object in a photo of it, clearly the edge length will not agree with actual dimensions of an object

Comment: @Buraian No, but do you know what would agree? The subtended solid angle.

Answer (score 0):

This question goes all the way back to Plato, if not earlier. Definitions are different than measurements. As stated above, the length of the ruler is invariant; the perspective by which you see it is not. You can change your distance, angle of view, etc, but physics sees the ruler as an absolute, or at least independent of the dimensions in which you measure it. Think of the ruler as the common denominator by which all perspectives measure it, whether that be in inches, centimeters, or Angstroms. THAT number does not depend on how far away you are when you view it. It is this subjective experience that allows people to be fooled so easily by optical illusions.

Comment: To view it as a person, one needs to see it through a prespective. You can't escape that. How can one claim that that there is some fundamental quantity beyond

Answer (score 0):

You are describing **angular** or **apparent size**, which is indeed dependent on distance/perspective. The Sun and the Moon are vastly different sizes, but have nearly identical angular diameters when viewed from the Earth, since the Sun is vastly further away. The apparent size of an object is useful for particular applications, but typically it's more useful to measure the size of an object independent of the position of the observer. Apparent size has uses in astronomy where the position of the observer with respect to the observed object usually has little variation, but it makes little sense to use apparent size in situations where the observer can get closer to/further from the observed object at will, which covers virtually all everyday applications.

Comment: The only size a person can perceive is apparent. Since we view each object in prespective...

Answer (score 0):

You can place both rulers so the lengths are touching. This way you can ensure they are the same length without perspective distortions.

If somehow you were not able to do this then you would have to sample the measurements from different angles/positions to account for the perspective distortions you talk about. This is needed in the case of astronomical observations as we can't reach out and move these objects about at will. So I would look at astronomy books to get more information about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Length measurements are not at all dependent on perspective. If you can measure the length of the same object from different perspectives and get different results, it indicates that your measurement method is flawed.

The apparent size of an object and its actual size are two different things.  Objects do not literally grow larger as you move towards them and smaller as you move away, that's an optical illusion, a quirk of the way our vision works.

The perspective problem only appears when you try to measure by visual estimation alone, and disappears when other methods are used; It's not a fundamental property of the world, just a flaw of a specific measurement method.